# Restore image to orignal size in responsive web page

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<style>
.some_photos { width: 358px; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1040px)
{
.some_photos { width: 700px; }
}
</style>
```

When the screen width of the device/browser is greater than 1040px I need .some_photos to resize to it's original image size because the photo may physically not be 700px wide in some cases. Photos will not be smaller than 358px but when some photos that is 400px for example resizes to 700px it does not look very good. I would rather display the image in it's original size. (400px for example)

This style sheet is used in a script that displays images in a gallery. The images that are bigger than 700px may not display bigger than 700px when the device/browser resolution is 1040px or higher.

I can't seem to find a CSS solution to resize the image to it's original size when the device/browser is larger than 1040px.

I have tried `.some_photos { max-width:100%; height:auto; }` when the device browser resolution is bigger than 1040px but that is not working.

Comment: use `width: auto` to overwrite your width

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
.some_photos 
{ 
   width: auto;
   height: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried this according to your needs description

```
.some_photos { width: 358px; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1040px)
{
.some_photos { width: auto; max-width: 700px; }
}
```